# Changing color of action bar doesn't work in ICS

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am changing the colour of action bar using the following code.

```
            actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(backgroundColor));
```

This works perfectly fine in `onCreate()` method(i.e when my activity starts).

But when I am using the same code in **Android 4.1** to change color of action bar in onClick() method(i.e when user clicks say a button) then it changes the color of action bar to 'white' ONLY whatsoever be the value of backgroundColor.

In **Android 2.3** it works perfectly fine in both cases, whether called from onCreate or onClick().

It seems to be dead end for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like for **Android 4.0** up to **Android 4.1** (4.2 is ok) you cannot change the action bar background once the activity has started.

So I guess a solution in those cases is to restart the activity with a different background color.

Not very elegant but thats the best I can come up with.

Something like this perhaps:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("color")) {
      getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
          new ColorDrawable(getIntent().getIntExtra("color", 0)));
    }

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent it = getIntent();
        it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        it.putExtra("color", Color.BLUE);
        startActivity(it);

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: yeah it will workaround. But actually I have a whole listview with different colors as providing theme option to user, and relaunching the activity will refresh the listview to top.

Comment: Dunno if this of interest but the holoeverywhere library: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere  has theme changing functionality in its demo application.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I used to solve this problem was to maintain a reference to the ColorDrawable that was used to set the background initially.  Then, to change its colour, modify the colour of the Drawable, and then tell the activity to invalidate its options, which causes the ActionBar to be redrawn.  Here's my code to set the action bar color:

```
ColorDrawable sBackgroundDrawable;
...
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
protected void setActionBarColor(int color){
    if(getSherlockActivity() != null && !mCallback.isNavDrawerShowing()){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            if(sBackgroundDrawable == null){
                sBackgroundDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
                getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(sBackgroundDrawable);
            }else{
                sBackgroundDrawable.setColor(color);
                getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }else{
            getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using ActionBarSherlock but I was able to solve the issues by keeping a reference to the color drawable thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what [steve_the_kid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395376/steve-the-kid) mentioned I was able to solve this by saving the color drawable.

```
ColorDrawable actionBarBackground = new ColorDrawable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground());
  actionBarBackground.setColor(someColor);
}

void onSomethingClick() {
  actionBarBackground.setColor(someOtherColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a late reply,But to help others I am replying to this question after so long.

Just set the Title of the action bar or make change in the icons or menu along with changing the colorDrawables.A simple change will recreate the action bar with new color.Even if you need same title or icon every time set same title or same icon.

I hope this will help others